# Call API with axios and API response code 200 but not show box for download file response

Tags: node.js, api, post, axios, response

When I call API according to the code below

```
<form action="http://158.108.168.11:9997/upload"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It response 200 and show box for download file
[Picture box for download file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq05R.png)

But When I call API according to the code below

```
 <form action="/upload"  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

```
router.post("/upload", multer.single('file'), async(req, res) => {
    const fileRecievedFromClient = req.file; 
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fileRecievedFromClient.buffer, fileRecievedFromClient.originalname);
    form.append('name', req.body.name);

    await axios.post('http://158.108.168.11:9997/upload', form, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary};`,
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="filename.clf"`,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",

            }
        })
});
```

It response 200 but not show box for download file
[API RESPONSE CODE 200 just not download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPmVi.png)

Comment: There's no code here that shows an alert box...

Comment: Sorry I mean [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq05R.png) @Brad